# AWS - Merge cloudformation stack with a VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a stack in AWS CloudFormation, My template basically consists of Ec2 instance, RDS instance for DB (MySQL engine) and a S3 bucket. but, its throwing error stating (db.t2.micro) this DB instance class cannot be created without a VPC, then I changed the DB instance class to (db.m1.small) again am getting same error. I even created a VPC too, but not sure how do I create my stack within the VPC which I created. I work in my company's AWS account. where already few other VPCs are available.

Thanks in advance :)

Modified the JSON script after getting answers. This script is in working condition and could create stack. TESTED!

**Updated Code**

```
    {  
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",   
    "Resources": {  
        "DBSubnetGroup": {  
            "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup",   
            "Properties": {  
                "DBSubnetGroupDescription": "This subnet belongs to Abdul's VPC",   
                "DBSubnetGroupName": "somename",   
                "SubnetIds": [  
                    "subnet-f6b15491",   
                    "subnet-b154569e"  
                ]  
            }  
        },   
        "DB": {  
            "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBInstance",   
            "Properties": {  
                "AllocatedStorage": "5",   
                "StorageType": "gp2",   
                "DBInstanceClass": "db.m1.small",   
                "DBName": "wordpress",   
                "Engine": "MySQL",   
                "MasterUsername": "wordpress",   
                "MasterUserPassword": "Word12345",   
                "DBSubnetGroupName": {  
                    "Ref": "DBSubnetGroup"  
                }  
            }  
        },   
        "EC2": {  
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",   
            "Properties": {  
                "ImageId": "ami-c481fad3",     
                "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
                "SubnetId": "subnet-b154569e"               
            }  
        },   
        "S3": {  
            "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",   
            "Properties": {  
                "BucketName": "wp-abdultestbuck"  
            }  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: what about assigning security groups in the RDS code block ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an [AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbsubnet-group.html) and then reference in the [AWS::RDS::DBInstance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html#cfn-rds-dbinstance-dbsubnetgroupname)

```
  {
    "Resources": { 
        "DBSubnetGroup": {
            "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup",
            "Properties": {
            "DBSubnetGroupDescription": "",
            "SubnetIds": [ "<Subnet ID 1","<Subnet ID 2>" ],
            }
        },
        "DB": {
            "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBInstance",
            "Properties": {
                ....
                "DBSubnetGroupName": { "Ref": "DBSubnetGroup" }
            }
        },
        "EC2": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
            "Properties": {
              "ImageId": "ami-c481fad3",
              "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
              "SubnetId": "<SubnetID>"
            }
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, specify a subnet for the EC2 instance so that it goes into the same VPC.

Comment: Or you could specify `VPCSecurityGroups` in the template. That will automatically create the RDS instance in a VPC.

Comment: As per your suggestion created 2 subnets in my vpc and created a DBSubnetGroup in my code and referenced the same in EC2,S3 and DB. but am getting this error "Encountered unsupported property DBSubnetGroupName" I really appreciate your help Sudharsan & krishna Please check my updated code in question..

Comment: Thanks John I did it, getting an other error though."Encountered unsupported property DBSubnetGroupName"  Please check my updated code in question

Comment: for ec2 instance, it should be SubnetId, updated code in answer -https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-subnetid

Comment: Tried the same.. again same error is coming.. please check my updated code in question.. Error - Encountered unsupported property DBSubnetGroupName

Comment: S3 Don't need VPC, DBSubnetGroupName is specific to RDS and it wont work with any other resource.

Comment: After removing DBSubnetGroup reference from S3, it worked. My Stack got created successfully.. Many thanks Sudharsan !! Not only for helping me out, but the way you explained things with useful links are just amazing.. Hatsoff !!!